# How to fix Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol on debian?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, debian, debian-buster

I have installed sql server developer edition on my debian 10 linux, and I can connect to my localhost with no problem. I have a database which I could connect to it by a specific connection, for this purpose I have to connect to a gateway through pptp vpn, but when I want to connect with this command at my terminal:

```
# sqlcmd -S <server name> -U <username> -P <password>
```

I face with these messages:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

Do you know how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: On *nixy machines sqlcmd uses OpenSSL. You probably need to edit the [/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/config.5ssl.html) on your client computer to tweak the MinProtocol version to be compatible with the SQL Server you're connecting to, especially if it's an older edition of SQL Server.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks man! That's the solution! It worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

OS: Ubuntu 20/22

Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded OpenSSL to version 3.0.2, which is more strict in its security policies. So, we need to downgrade the policy settings to fetch the data

Create a config file somewhere (e.g. ~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf with following content:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

Then run your command like this:

```
 OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S <> -U <> -P <>
```

Thanks, [plumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo) for the reference.